# Proving a Subspace

Tags: vector-spaces

Let V = C, the complex numbers viewed as a vector space over C.
Let W be the subset of real numbers.

Determine if W is a subspace of the vector space V.
Give a complete proof using the subspace theorem, or else give a specific example to show that some subspace property fails.

What I've done so far is:
(0) W is not empty as 0 is found in this subset.

How would I prove (or dis-prove) using vector addition and scalar multiplication?

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{R},+$ is a group, so the additive property is also true. What fails here is the multiplication by scalar. For example $1\in\mathbb{R}$, but $i\cdot 1=i$ is not.

Answer (score 1):

You have to show that W satisfies 3 conditions:

1) The zero vector 0 is in W.
2) If u and v are elements of W, then the sum u + v is an element of W.
3) If u is an element of W and c is a scalar from C, then the product cu is an element of W.

even though the first two conditions hold.
The third property is not satisfied. Take $i\in \mathbb{C}$ (where $V=\mathbb{C}$) and the vector $2\in\mathbb{R}$ (where $W=\mathbb{R}$) the product $2i$ is clearly not in W.